# How do I redefine `Re`?

Tags: matrix

I want the `Re` function of the `Matrix` object to be evaluated to the trace of the argument of `Matrix` divided by its order. But this code does not work:

```
Unprotect[Re];
Re[Matrix[x_]] ^= Trace[x]/Length[x];
Protect[Re];
```

Can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Tr`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tr.html) is the trace of a matrix

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Matrix /: Re[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ]] := Tr[x]/Length[x]

mat = Array[a, {3, 3}];

Re[Matrix[mat]]

(* 1/3 (a[1, 1] + a[2, 2] + a[3, 3]) *)
```